# Lines tab gray out in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, layout, ribbon

Lines tab within Analysis group under Layout ribbon grayout in Excel 2013, the Trendline tab is not,  is there a way to activate it? wanted to use Lines to create series line along the columns on Chart. Can please shade lights, Thanks.

Comment: Care to share a screenshot so people can get an idea what you're talking about? What Lines tab? What ribbon? It must be a context ribbon, so what is the context that shows the ribbon?

Comment: There's a layout ribbon in Power View, but it does not have an Analysis group. Please explain your context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must mean Excel 2010, not 2013. In Excel 2010, with a chart selected, there is a Layout ribbon in the chart tools, which has an Analysis group.

The Lines tool is only available when the selected chart is a line chart. Adding drop lines to column charts does not make sense, so it is not available for column charts.

[image]